# 404 on FacesServlet causes infinite loop with java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.flash.FlashImpl.isKeepMessages

Tags: jsf, http-status-code-404, infinite-loop, myfaces, websphere-8

In WebSphere 8.5, accessing `/myapp`, `/myapp/`, `/myapp/nosuchpage` and `/myapp/faces/nosuchpage` will procude a 404, which is fine. But `/myapp/faces` and `/myapp/faces/` causes instead of 404 an infinite loop with a NPE on MyFaces Flash scope as seen in the log.

```java
[3/6/15 16:58:03:391 CST] 000000f7 SystemOut     O [PhaseListener:beforePhase] phase=RESTORE_VIEW(1)
[3/6/15 16:58:03:391 CST] 000000f7 SystemOut     O [PhaseListener:beforePhase] phase=RENDER_RESPONSE(6)
[3/6/15 16:58:03:391 CST] 000000f7 SystemOut     O [PhaseListener:beforePhase] fc.viewRoot.viewId=/faces/ fc.application.viewHandler.actionURL=/jsfTest2/faces//faces/
... (repeats)
[3/6/15 16:58:03:392 CST] 000000f7 SystemOut     O [PhaseListener:beforePhase] phase=RESTORE_VIEW(1)
[3/6/15 16:58:03:392 CST] 000000f7 SystemOut     O [PhaseListener:beforePhase] phase=RENDER_RESPONSE(6)
[3/6/15 16:58:03:392 CST] 000000f7 SystemOut     O [PhaseListener:beforePhase] fc.viewRoot.viewId=/faces/ fc.application.viewHandler.actionURL=/jsfTest2/faces//faces/
[3/6/15 16:58:03:405 CST] 000000f7 ErrorPageWrit E   An exception occurred
                                 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.PhaseListenerManager.informPhaseListenersAfter(PhaseListenerManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:186)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:119)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1111)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:367)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.jsp.JspViewDeclarationLanguage.buildView(JspViewDeclarationLanguage.java:94)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:66)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:240)
    ... (repeats)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1111)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3901)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1865)

[3/6/15 16:58:03:429 CST] 000000f7 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: An exception was thrown by one of the service methods of the servlet [Faces Servlet] in application [jsfTest2EAR]. Exception created : [java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.flash.FlashImpl.isKeepMessages(FlashImpl.java:394)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.flash.FlashImpl._saveMessages(FlashImpl.java:669)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.flash.FlashImpl.doPostPhaseActions(FlashImpl.java:275)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:252)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1111)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:367)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.jsp.JspViewDeclarationLanguage.buildView(JspViewDeclarationLanguage.java:94)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:66)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:240)
    ... (repeats)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1111)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3901)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1865)
]
[3/6/15 16:58:03:442 CST] 000000f7 LocalTranCoor E   WLTC0017E: Resources rolled back due to setRollbackOnly() being called.
... (repeats)
[3/6/15 16:58:04:523 CST] 000000f7 SRTServletRes W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse setStatus WARNING: Cannot set status. Response already committed.
[3/6/15 16:58:04:523 CST] 000000f7 SRTServletRes W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse addHeader SRVE8094W: WARNING: Cannot set header. Response already committed.
```

Adding `<error-page>` for 404 does not help. No such looping is observed in WebSphere 6.1. Perhaps a bug in MyFaces bundled in WebSphere 8.5?

This is my `web.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

    <display-name>jsfTest2</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.ibm.ws.jsf.JSP_UPDATE_CHECK</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.ibm.ws.jsf.LOAD_FACES_CONFIG_AT_STARTUP</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>-1</load-on-startup>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <async-supported>false</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: To exclude one and other, clear browser cookies on the domain (or spawn an incognito window) and retry.

Comment: unfortunately, still looping after clearing cookies or going incognito.

Comment: OK, what if you open a Facelets (XHTML) file instead of a JSP file?

Comment: i hope i'm not mistaken, but it fails only when opening `/faces` or `/faces/`, without any filename or path following.

Comment: Ah, thus it doesn't fail when explicitly opening `/myapp/faces/index.jsp` or `/myapp/faces/some.xhtml`? That wasn't clear from the question at all.

Comment: sorry about missing the obvious (to me) cases.  it works with `/myapp/faces/index.jsp`.  FileNotFoundException with `/myapp/faces/index.xhtml`.

Comment: OK, what if you replace the both JSF 1.0-style `/faces/*` and `*.faces` mappings by only one JSF 2.0-style `*.xhtml` mapping? Alter URLs accordingly to always use `*.xhtml` instead of `/faces/*.jsp` (and in the meanwhile, take opportunity to get rid of `javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX` altogether, as that's supposed to be the default value already)

Comment: after much negotiation with IBM, they acknowledged that it's an issue with myfaces, then opened an APAR, and sent us a test-fix for verification.

Comment: the issue is filed under PI38066 [http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI38066]; the fix for which is targeted for inclusion in WebSphere 8.5.5 fix pack 6.